# Yii join tables on column other than PK

Tags: activerecord, yii

I'm using the [Gallery Manager](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/imagesgallerymanager/) extension which has a Gallery model connected with a one-to-many relation to the GalleryPhotos model (gallery_photo.gallery_id FK to gallery.id).

I have a Products model that I want to join to a Gallery model with a one-to-one relation.

How would I define such a relation given that I don't want to modify the Gallery table (to add a FK).
One option I thought about is adding a gallery_id field to my Products table that would point to Gallery->id but how would I define the relationships in my Products model file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would I define such a relation given that I don't want to modify
>   the Gallery table (to add a FK). One option I thought about is adding
>   a gallery_id field to my Products table that would point to
>   Gallery->id but how would I define the relationships in my Products
>   model file?

if you use one-to-one relation as situation method, you can do that but it will cause any developer that would inherit your code wonder why original guy has done like that. I think it does not matter with you right now therefore I call it is `situation method`

Assume this is how it works: `adding a gallery_id field to my Products table that would point to Gallery->id`

In function `relations()` of Product model

```
'Gallery' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Gallery', 'gallery_id')
```

In function `relations()` of Gallery model

```
'Product' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Product', 'gallery_id'),
```